# vim: jump back, don't use existing tab?

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I hava goto the function defination using youcompleteme.the function defination is in a new file,so the vim open a new tab.but when I jump back through `ctrl+o`,it changed the current buf to the previce tab.So,there is two same tab in vim.I don't want this,how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `:tabprevious`?

Comment: You should investigate why your plugin opens the definition in a new tab page to begin with.

Comment: youcomplteme,`ycm_goto_buffer_command='new-or-existing-tab'`,I want to open  new tab if the definition is in another file,but when I  jump back to the old position,I don't want  two or more same file tab.

Comment: You have to implement a custom variant of `Ctrl-O` that checks other tabs for the buffer. There is no built-in command for that.

Comment: You should use buffers instead of tab pages until you understand what a tab page is.